# Why use "and" in a for loop and "or" in a while loop for obtaining the same result...?

Tags: loops, for-loop

Why use "and" in a for loop and "or" in a while loop for obtaining the same result...?

Why use "and" in a for loop and "or" in a while loop for obtaining the same result...?

Comment: You should give us an example to illustrate your question, because right now it's quite unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: _Probably_ because the logic is inverted. Which we cannot judge without seeing it. !(A && B) == !A || !B